# How to call an API with multiple pages using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I do have an API that I need to fetch into my react app. The challenge is the number of total pages doesn't exist in the API where I have the example. Also, every API call limit only gets 1000 records at a time. I do have a button that is supposed to go page by page, but I don't think it's working as it should, after all the data is fetched, it would still make an API call. My question is :

1. How do I fetch the API so all the 5000 records will populate even though there's a limit
2. How do I make the button to fetch API to load 1000 records at a time that doesn't disappear, because the button is buggy, when I click on it, it'll fetch 1000, but it disappears.

   ```
   const perPage = 1000;
     const [page, setPage] = useState([]);
     const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);
     const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
     const [load, setload] = useState([]);

     useEffect(() => {
       const getUserList = () => {
         setLoading(true);
         fetch(
           `/forms?page=${page}&count=${perPage}`,
           { headers }
         )
           .then((res) => res.json())
           .then((res) => {
             //setTotalPages(res.total_pages);
             setload(res.elements);
              setUserList(res.elements);
               setPage(res.page);
             if (res.elements.length === 0) {
               console.log("array is empty");
               alert("empty");
               setLoading(false);
             }

             console.log(res);
           });
       };
       getUserList();
     }, [page]);

     return (
       <div className="App">

         {userList.map((x, i) => {
           return (
             <div key={i} className="box">
               <div className="name">{x.name + 1} </div>
             </div>
           );
         })}

       <button className="btn-load-more" onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>
         {loading ? "Loading..." : "Load More"}
       </button>

       </div>
     );
   ```

   ```
       {
       "elements": [{
       "type": "LandingPage",
       "currentStatus": "Draft",
       "id": "21",
       "createdAt": "1424811452",
       "createdBy": "5",
       "depth": "minimal",
       "folderId": "3655",
       "name": "Default Landing Page",
       "permissions": ["Retrieve", "SetSecurity", "Delete", "Update"],
       "updatedAt": "1424811452",
       "updatedBy": "5",
       "excludeFromAuthentication": "false",
       "htmlContent": {
       "type": "StructuredHtmlContent",
       "contentSource": "editor"
       },
       "relativePath": "/Default_LP"
       }, {
       "type": "LandingPage",
       "currentStatus": "Draft",
       "id": "22",
       "createdAt": "1432583568",
       "createdBy": "9",
       "depth": "minimal",
       "folderId": "3655",
       "name": "Test Landing Page",
       "permissions": ["Retrieve", "SetSecurity", "Delete", "Update"],
       "updatedAt": "1432583653",
       "updatedBy": "9",
       "excludeFromAuthentication": "false",
       "htmlContent": {
       "type": "RawHtmlContent",
       "contentSource": "upload"
       },
       "relativePath": "/Test_Landing_Page"
       }],
       "page": 1,
       "pageSize": 1000,
       "total": 5000
       }
   ```

`

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. See [ask].

Comment: You are using setPage(res.page) inside UseEffect with [page] dependancy which cause infinite loop. You should not use [page] dependancy or route your logic to 2 separte hooks

Comment: @SergeyKhmelevskoy how would you change the code? I'm a little lost here

Comment: @SergeyKhmelevskoy how would you go through the page then if you don't have total pages? can you elaborate, please? thanks

Comment: Maybe move your if statement before the part where you set your load to res.elements. Also if you want to store all elements, make load an array and update it like so: setLoad(prev => [...prev, res.elements])

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeMakroglou i got an error for making this change "          setload((prev) => [...prev, res.elements]);
" Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: prev is not iterable

Comment: try setload(prev => [...prev, ...res.elements])

Comment: @GeorgeMakroglou still no luck... same error

Comment: Something goes into your state that is not an array. If you start with an empty array and then spread another array it should work. console.log() res before updating your state.

Comment: When i do console.log(res)  before updating the state this is what I get....{elements: Array(100), page: 1, pageSize: 100, total: 226}

Comment: @GeorgeMakroglou would you be able to show it on in an code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be fair, if you know that the API will always have 5 total pages and it doesn't block multiple requests, I would do it in the following way:

```
export default function SomeComponent(){

   useEffect(() => {
    

    (async () => {
       try {
          let promises = [];

          new Array(5).forEach(page => {
               let promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
               try {
                   let response = await fetch('your url');
                   let json = await response.json();
                   if(response.status !== 200) reject("ERR: " + response.status)
                   resolve(json)
               }catch(err){
                   reject(err.message)
               }
            })
            promises.push(promise)
          })

         let results = await Promise.all(promises)
         //here you have all 5000 rows unless a request fails

       }catch(err){
         //handle the error
       }
     
    })()
        
   }, [])


   return (
      //your jsx here
   )
}
```

**UPDATE**
I opened a sandbox and used randomuser.me which has paginated endpoints and made it work with your approach so there is probably something going wrong with the value you add in setload(). The only extra thing I did is to add an AbortController for React 18 useEffect() double render. In this example I don't have the next page number or the total but if you have them you can calculate the final request with something like

```
if(page === total/perPage){
 ...
}
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let abortController = new AbortController();
    let { signal } = abortController;
    fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/?page=${page}&results=10`, {
      signal
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setUsers((prev) => [...prev, ...data.results]);
        if (page < 10) {
          console.log(page);
          setPage(page + 1);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.name === "AbortError") {
          setUsers([]);
        }
      });

    return () => {
      abortController.abort();
    };
  }, [page]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's the tricky part...is there a way to program this so that it would go through all pages without knowing how many pages exist?

Comment: I updated the answer to do it  "dynamically". It's artificial but it fits your case. It's not suggested though cause not knowing the amount of data may cause large waiting times, and slow the app during parsing and rendering. You could as well receive 5 million rows that way.

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain why you added this? if (page < 10) {
          console.log(page);
          setPage(page + 1);
        } 

also the page should be an empty array in my const?   const [page, setPage] = useState([]); or set to 1 as default?

Comment: With React 18 they added a double render "feature" lets say, so during development and while you are in StrictMode all your components get mounted, then unmounted and then mounted back. They did this to make sure that bugs are caught in development and to ensure that developers return cleanup functions in their effects that destroy the components properly (close sockets, remove listeners, cancel requests etc). The AbortController is there to allow me to cancel the request during this process and in actuall real world scenarios where the component gets destroyed during a request.

Comment: I added this to simulate the end of the pagination because randomuser.me doesn't provide info like total_results, page_number, and results_per_page. If you have this info you can calculate when is the last page. The default is 1 cause your first page will always be 1. I haven't seen a paginated API that is zero-based.

Comment: There's only one problem with the code you have, I made an API call to another set of data, the total was less than 1000 but there was 4,5 extra API calls

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-dijkstra-xohbge?file=/src/App.js Check the sandbox I run it multiple times and always have 10 requests. Did you leave there the if() clause for page < 10 ?

Comment: Thanks for the link. No, I didn't remove the if() clause.... see if you only have 1000 or 2000 records, there will be 8 unnecessary API calls. My API stores a 1000 records each, the API calls that I see on my console logs are repeated

Comment: here's a screenshot: 
[![Screen-Shot-2022-06-27-at-8-05-54-PM.png](https://i.postimg.cc/kgm1GGHQ/Screen-Shot-2022-06-27-at-8-05-54-PM.png)](https://postimg.cc/XpscDj4q)

Comment: Yes you have to modify it according to your needs, I don't have info about your API. What I showed you is just a demo that you can do it dynamically.

Comment: where would I have to put this to stop the request? 
if(page === total/perPage){
         
         }
Also, when I added this   if (totalcount > 1000) {
          console.log(page);
          setPage(page + 1);
        }
it didn't go to other pages...
[![Screen-Shot-2022-06-27-at-8-58-15-PM.png](https://i.postimg.cc/brFRTNYv/Screen-Shot-2022-06-27-at-8-58-15-PM.png)](https://postimg.cc/MfVRZwQk)

Again, my API only takes a 1000 per page

Comment: This was just an example, maybe you can have a sum with the results you have retrieved and compare it to the total to stop the request. I just gave you an example of a possible calculation. If it doesn't go to the next page, you are probably not using the variable. Play around with it and try to understand what goes wrong.

Comment: It goes to a different page but in an infinite loop. In which section of the code do you add to stop the request?

Comment: if the amount of data you receive is equal to the total number of rows your API can provide then you don't update the page. The code can remain as it is, and it can work with any paginated API as long as you tweak the if() clause. Instead of checking for the page, everytime you receive a response, add the number of rows received to a variable (request 1: 50, request 2: 100 etc.) and then compare this with the total. If it's less than the total increment your page.